# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, html, database

I'm trying to access a sql database. I created in VS2013 C#. But I keep getting this error

> 'Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login
>   failed.'

I'm trying to run this off localhost with IIS manager. Am I pointing to the datasource wrong for my connectionstring in web config? I have the mdf and log files in the wrong place maybe? i created the mdf and log files and place them in my app_data folder instead.

```
       //objects we will need to work with the db
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmd;

        //IF PAGE IS NOT A POSTBACK, ADD A HIT
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //connect to the db
            //conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source");
            conn = new  
               SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
               ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            //the sql command to increment hits by 1
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Hits SET Hits = Hits+1 WHERE 
            Name=@Name", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //update where Name is 'Default' which corresponds to this page
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "WebForm1");

            using (conn)
            {
                //open the connection
                conn.Open();
                //send the query
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }


        //DISPLAY HITS IN OUR LABEL
        //connect to the db
        conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].
                 ConnectionString);

        //the sql command to select the row of hits corresponding to this           
        page

        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Hits WHERE Name=@Name", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //select where Name is 'Default' which corresponds to this page
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "WebForm1");

        using (conn)
        {
            //open the connection
            conn.Open();
            //send the query and store the results in a sqldatareader
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.Read())
            {
                //set the text of our label to the current # of hits
                lblHits.Text = "Default Page Hits - " +  
                rdr["Hits"].ToString();
            }
        }
```

my connection string in web.config

```
<configuration>

   <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
   </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=            
     (local)\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=Database; Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't see any username and password in the `connectionstring`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Initial Catalog` is wrong.  Either remove this from the connection string or use the correct catalog name.

Also you need to provide credentials in the connection string, try

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Comment: The sql database file i created in VS was called Database.mdf.  Shouldn't the syntax for the Initial Catalog be Initial Catalog=Database.

Comment: Maybe you need login credentials, see updated answer.

Comment: Still no luck. I'm still getting the same error Cannot open database "Database" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'desktop\desktopcomp'.  The debugger is pointing to  conn.Open();

Comment: I fiddled around with sql database before, didn't have any trouble that time. A nagging feeling keeps telling me it might be because my datasource is wrong,

Answer (score 0):

I just had a typo in the connection string and was targeting my old sql-server after correcting it it worked.

Comment: It is not the answer to the original question.

Comment: it is I received the same error message cause I changed user in the meantime